# Pandas Python DataFrame format conversion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image: Current DF]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXqMe.png) **Pandas DF is available in this format but I want to convert in another format which is image** [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSoBs.png).

[image: Need to convert in this format]

Please provide any idea about how can i convert.

Comment: see dupe - also have a read of [mcve] and [ask] images are not acceptable for examples on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.melt`:

```
out = df.melt(['DateTime', 'Machine'], var_name='Variable', value_name='Value') \
        .sort_values('DateTime', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)

# Output:
              DateTime Machine     Variable  Value
0  2021-02-01 09:26:00      GE  Temperature     30
1  2021-02-01 09:26:00      GE        Speed   1200
2  2021-02-01 09:25:00      GE  Temperature     32
3  2021-02-01 09:25:00      GE        Speed   1200
4  2021-02-01 09:24:00      GE  Temperature     35
5  2021-02-01 09:24:00      GE        Speed   1200
6  2021-02-01 09:23:00      GE  Temperature     26
7  2021-02-01 09:23:00      GE        Speed   1200
8  2021-02-01 09:22:00      GE  Temperature     31
9  2021-02-01 09:22:00      GE        Speed   1200
10 2021-02-01 09:21:00      GE  Temperature     32
11 2021-02-01 09:21:00      GE        Speed   1200
12 2021-02-01 09:20:00      GE  Temperature     35
13 2021-02-01 09:20:00      GE        Speed   1200
14 2021-02-01 09:19:00      GE  Temperature     38
15 2021-02-01 09:19:00      GE        Speed   1200
```

Comment: Hi, It solves the problem for this DF. But for another DF it shows error: ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: You have to update your version of Pandas. What is your version?

Comment: pandas 1.3.5 version

Comment: Can you share your data? Do you have columns with the same name?

Comment: I couldn't attach the table.. sorry.. it's with different names and time column.. I changed the column name in the code you sent

Comment: Or you have a column that contains arrays and not scalar values.

Comment: yes, now I changed to DF using pd.DataFrame(df, columns = [' ']. The code line is working with converting the format but all values are NAN.

Comment: I mean not in column name. I think you have a column values that contain arrays.

Comment: Yeah mate.. it's working now... thanks a lot